# How to I minimize/maximize dijit splitter by click?

Tags: dojo, splitter

I want the dijit splitter to minimize when user click it and go back to its position when clicked again (I don't care for the draggable feature)

how do I do it ?

In this example I want the panel on the right to minimize when click on the splitter

```
http://77.235.53.170/split/split.htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use [dojox.layout.ExpandoPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/layout/ExpandoPane.html) at your left pane.

```
var bc = new BorderContainer({
    splitter:true, 
    gutters:false
}, containerDiv);

new ExpandoPane({
    region:"left",
    title: "Expandable pane",
    className: yourClassName
}).placeAt(bc);
```

**EDIT:** update based on request:

1. put this in your head:

   <link href="js/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
2. change you pane like this:

   ```
   <div id="leftCol" class="edgePanel" title="Left Expando" data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ExpandoPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Left Expando', region: 'leading', splitter: true" style="width: 250px;">
       <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 400px; height: 95%;"
           tabstrip="true">
           <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Layers" selected="true">
               <div id="CheckboxTree">
               </div>
           </div>                
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: It doesn't work so good on my test.
Also , clicking on the splitter doesn't auto resize...

Comment: What do you mean "clicking on the splitter doesn't auto resize.", you can drag it to auto resize. And minimize it by click top-right icon.

Comment: I've added updated URL with the current code I use. Can you explain a little bit detailed what to do ? because I didn't understand.
Thank you !!!

Comment: Thank you , its working now. Why do you prefer using programmatic code vs declarative code?

Comment: Also , How can I change the animation direction of the collapse? My site is dir=rtl but animation is still ltr

Comment: I like programmatic code vs declarative code because I can full control everything and the performance is better. I don't need switch between html and javascript back and forth all the time. Regard to your dir=rtl issue, I didn't use it before.  But can you try use "right/left" instead of "leading"?

Comment: changing to right solved the animation (the button also moved ,but its easy to fix).
I'll have more dojo questions soon , Thx A lot ! :-)